# how to make first url parameter random string value in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

I am doing a project on CI, And I wish the project should look like this `www.twitter.com/username` . Here `twitter` will be my project folder and `username` should be get from database.  How can I make it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide more details.

Comment: yeah. in my first url parameter I would like to retrieve the username from the database. If it exist there retrieve from there else redirect to error route.. And thanks for your help. I am using this route method and think this is useful for me ... '$route['(:any)'] = 'profile/user/$1';' ..   Is there any other method for this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In route file add this below line. That is as Profile is as controller and user is as method.

```
'$route['(:any)'] = 'profile/user/$1';
```

Thats all. :)

Answer (score 0):

you should change the .htaccses file to remove the index.php from url like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

<Files "index.php">
AcceptPathInfo On
</Files>
```

then you need to remove the index.php from config.php file in the config folder like so:

```
$config['index_page'] = ''; //LEAVE EMPTY - NO INDEX.PHP
```

and then you can use the username in your default controller, but i still think you  will need another mehtod before the username, because you cant pass a parameter to index method